# Merge databases in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, database

I would like to merge two similarly constructed spatialite databases. I have tried to open a first database (1), add the second database (2) to the project and copy/paste the attribute table from (2) in the attribute table from (1)...it doesn't work (too simple I guess).
Similarly how can I merge two databases with very small differences (one created in QGIS Chugiak, the other in QGIS Nodebo)

Comment: Can you provide examples of what the small differences are between the two databases? Is it attribute column type or names, geometry mismatches?

Answer (score 2):

You would do this in DB Manager within QGIS and you would be doing a standard INSERT operation:

```
insert into spatialitedb_1 (
column1
, column2
, column3
, column4
)

select 
column1
, column2
, column3
, column4
from spatialitedb_2
```

The above assumes you have matching column names and column orders from both DB's. If not, you can re-arrange and alias non-matching column names like this:

```
insert into spatialitedb_1 (
    column1
    , column2
    , column3
    , column4
    )

    select 
    column1
    , othername as column2
    , column3
    , anothername as column4
    from spatialitedb_2
```